# why are "if" loops all skipped here?

Tags: c, loops, struct, switch-statement

So, this is my very first year of coding and I'm a beginner, I was asked to make a program that asks for the current date, displays it and shows the day after. I did this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


struct formatDate
{ int jour;
  int mois;
  int year;
};

int verifier(int jour, int mois, int year);






int main()
{   struct formatDate date;
    int day, month, annee;

    printf("veuilliez entrer la date sous le format suivant : jj mm aaaa \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &date.jour, &date.mois, &date.year);
    day=date.jour; month=date.mois; annee=date.year;

   if ( verifier(day, month, annee) == 1)
   {
        printf(" la date que vous avez entré est : %d / %d / %d\n", date.jour, date.mois, date.year);

        if (annee % 4 == 0)
        {
            if ((month == 2) && (day == 28 ) )
            {
                day=29;
                printf("la date du lendemain est %d / %d / %d ", day, month, annee);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if((month == 2) && (day == 28))
            {
                day=1; month=3;
                printf("la date du lendemain est %d / %d / %d", day, month, annee);
            }
        }

        if ((month==12) && (day==31))
        {
            day=1; 
            month=1; 
            annee=annee+1;
            printf ("la date du lendemain est %d / %d / %d", day, month, annee);
         }

         if ((month =! 12) && (day == 31))
         {
             day=1; 
             month=month+1;
             printf("la date du lendemain est %d / %d / %d", day, month, annee);
         }

         if ((month == 4) ||(month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11))
         {
             if (day < 30 )
             {
                 day = day++;
             }
             else
             {
                 day=1; month++;
             }
             printf (" la date du lendemain est %d / %d / %d", day, month, annee);

         }
    }
    else
    {
       printf("la date que vous avez entré n'est pas valable\n");
    }

    return 0;
}





int verifier(int day, int month, int annee)
{
    return 1;
    if ( (month > 12) && (day > 31) )
        return 0;
    if (annee % 4 ==! 0)
    {     if ((month == 2) && (day > 28 ) )
              return 0;

    }

    else {
            if((day > 29) && (month == 2))
                return 0;
         }

    switch(month)
       {
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            if (day > 30)
                return 0;
                break;
        }


}
```

The problem is that it displays the current date, but skips all of what written below, and I don't know what's wrong, it doesn't works even the syntax is correct ( or at least, CodeBlocks didn't spot any)

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're asking about their differences. (And there is no such thing as an "if loop".)

Comment: You can figure out where it's going wrong by either stepping through execution with a debugger, or adding temporary `printf()` statements and running the program again, and watching what gets printed and what does not get printed, until you understand the exact code path that is being taken.  Once you've identified the exact line that isn't behaving the way you expected it to, you will have an easier time figuring out why it isn't.

Comment: Everything in the function after `return 1;` is unreachable code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: It doesn't skip the statements, if you enter a date that is checked, for example `31 12 2000`.

Comment: Don't write `day = day++;`. `day = day + 1;`, `day += 1;`, `++day;`, or `day++;` are all fine, but don't combine them.

Comment: `annee % 4 ==! 0` is a weird way of writing `annee % 4 == 1`, which is wrong. Also, not all years divisible by 4 are leap years. Those divisible by 100 aren't. But those divisible by 400 are.

Comment: In fact `day = day++;` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WeatherVane If my rusty C knowledge doesn't play me a trick, `verifier` will always return "1", regardless input.

Comment: @Fildor I noticed that, my comment was about the other conditional statements in `main`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, get it. Then we're on the same page.

Comment: I tried to fix indentation a little bit. I think it's clearer now, not perfect. Can you name some of the values you have tested with?

Comment: You are overcomplicating the procedure. Add 1 to the day. If it is now more than the number of days in the month, set the day to 1 and add 1 to the month. If the month is now greater than 12, set the month to 1 and add 1 to the year. Print the result. Done.

Comment: In case OP missed it the first time: there is no such thing as an _if loop_.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had three problems that I identified and corrected and I will explain why

1-line 55

```
                      /////////  eror  ////////
                   if ((month =! 12) && (day == 31))
Here is how to write it correctly:
                   if ((month != 12) && (day == 31))
```

2- line 65

```
                      /////////  eror  //////// 
                           if (day < 30 )
                           {
                              day = day++;
                           }
Here is how to write it correctly:
                             day=day+1;  or  day++;


3-in function verifier return1 It should not be written at the beginning of the function because it leaves the function when it is reached
```

I hope your problem is solved.